# different linewidth for different columns using pandas plot

Tags: python

I am using the below lines to plot dataframe using different linewidths for different columns. I got an error of  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

I don't understand, why? it should be ok to use a list for assigning different lines width for different columns.  Can anyone find the problem? Thanks

```
linewidth=[3 if 'spy500' in sector.lower() else 1 for sector in pct_above_ma_allsectors.columns]

pct_above_ma_allsectors[-60:].plot(figsize = (15,8),linewidth=linewidth)
```

Comment: anyone can help me? Thanks